# Why python gave me Hot not really hot?

Tags: python

```
temp = 120
if temp > 85:
   print "Hot"
elif temp > 100:
   print "REALLY HOT!"
elif temp > 60:
   print "Comfortable" 
else:
   print "Cold"
```

Comment: Because 120 is greater than 85. Once its found a true condition it stops, you should change the order to suit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python picks the *first* condition that is true, and the rest of the `if..elif..else` branches are skipped.

`120 > 85` is true, so the first test passes and `'Hot'` is printed. It doesn't matter that the second test also matches after that point.

Put the `> 100` test *first*:

```
if temp > 100:
   print "REALLY HOT!"
elif temp > 85:
   print "Hot"
elif temp > 60:
   print "Comfortable" 
else:
   print "Cold"
```

Alternatively, limit the tests to exclude the upper range:

```
if 100 >= temp > 85:
   print "Hot"
elif temp > 100:
   print "REALLY HOT!"
elif temp > 60:
   print "Comfortable" 
else:
   print "Cold"
```